# Access msgbox Yes No to Choose Report - Opening Wrong Report?

Tags: ms-access, vba, report, msgbox

I set up the following simple code, to choose if the report should show "excluded" groups or not.

```
 Private Sub cmdRptWorktypesByGroups_Click()
     Dim rptExclYN As String

     rptExclYN = MsgBox("Would you like this report with excluded groups (Yes)" & vbclrf & " or without excluded practice groups (No)?", vbYesNo, "Choose Report With or Without excluded groups")

     If rptExclYN = Yes Then
         DoCmd.OpenReport "rptWorkTypebyGroups", acViewReport
     Else
         DoCmd.OpenReport "rptWorkTypebyGroupsNoExcl", acViewReport
     End If

 End Sub
```

That is my code.  It should be totally straight forward.  Problem is, that when the user clicks Yes, it opens the rptWorkTypebyGroupsNoExcl report.  When I click No, it still opens that same report.  Can anyone tell what I might be doing wrong?

I originally had the rptWorkTypebyGroups report, with a query record source.  I copied that report, renamed the copy as rptWorkTypebyGroupsNoExcl, and saved it's Record Source query as it's own name.  I can't tell why the message box isn't opening the right report.  Can anyone please help?

Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MsgBox()` function returns a `VbMsgBoxResult` value (an Integer), not a string.

Since you apparently don't have Option Explicit on, `Yes` is created as new empty Variant, so your If condition will always be false, no matter what you selected.

Put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module.
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

Correct code:

```vb
Private Sub cmdRptWorktypesByGroups_Click()

     Dim rptExclYN As VbMsgBoxResult 

     rptExclYN = MsgBox("Would you like this report with excluded groups (Yes)" & vbCrLf & " or without excluded practice groups (No)?", vbYesNo, "Choose Report With or Without excluded groups")

     If rptExclYN = vbYes Then
         DoCmd.OpenReport "rptWorkTypebyGroups", acViewReport
     Else
         DoCmd.OpenReport "rptWorkTypebyGroupsNoExcl", acViewReport
     End If

End Sub
```

**Edit:** It's `vbCrLf`, not `vbclrf`.
Another one that Option Explicit would have caught.

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate you taking the time to give me other pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a moron.  I was having it say if rptExclYN = Yes and not rptExclYN = vbYes.  My bad.  Here's the simple code that works:

```
Dim rptExclYN As Variant

rptExclYN = MsgBox("Would you like this report with excluded groups (Yes)" & vbCrLf & _
" or without excluded groups (No)?", vbYesNo, "Choose Report With or Without Excluded Groups")

If rptExclYN = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptWorkTypebyGroups", acViewReport
ElseIf rptExclYN = vbNo Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptWorkTypebyGroupsNoExcl", acViewReport
End If
```

Hope this helps someone else, because then it would mean I'm not the only one missing simple things.

Comment: Still, you should `Dim rptExclYN` as @Andre showed you.